# JasperReports: reports XLSX export worsksheet names

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a JR report being run from *JR Server* that I am exporting to Excel. It's 7 subreports that each get their own worksheet. If I export to **XSL** then the worksheet names I've created by setting the ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name*** property works correctly. If I export to **XLSX** format, which is about 1/3rd the size of **XLS**, the page names come out as page1, page2, etc.

Is there a way to format the worksheet names for **XLSX** output the same way there is for **XLS**?

I'm using *iReport* and *JasperReports Server* for creation and generation of the reports.

Comment: Hi jerca did you get any solution for this.I am struck at this.